# TeXstudio shortcuts custom buttons

Tags: texstudio, editors, shortcut, button

I would like to know how to set up buttons for math commands (such as fraction, square root, subscript and superscript, etc.) in Texstudio. I attach a screenshot of my Texstudio below.

[image: My texstudio toolbar]

I selected Options-->Configure Texstudio-->Shortcuts and I found a list of math commands. However I wasn't able to proceed further. Please see second screenshot below. For example how I can create a button on my toolbar representing the square root, so that when I click on it I get automatically `\sqrt{}`? (Just to be clear, I do **not** want to create or modify a keyboard shortcut)

[image: Configure texstudio shortcuts]

Comment: If you click in "Advanced", you will also get "Toolbars" there to fiddle with.

Comment: I did what you suggest but I don't see the new custom toolbars that I added

Comment: To enable the custom bar right click on one of the existing ones, you will get a menu on which you can then check "Custom".

Comment: Unfortunately StackExchange does not let me add any image in the comments, otherwise I'd attach a screenshot

Comment: You can edit your question, if need be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is what your question is asking for ?

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Nice "turbo screenshot"! (+1)

Comment: gusbrs not as quick as @marmot could draw it in TikZ  :-)

Comment: And it would even be animated in 3D!  :-)

Comment: @KJO Best explanation ever!